# QML based programm on TFT

Tags: touchscreen, opengles, qt

I wrote a program with QT so I could run it on my Raspberry. It's based on QML only. I made a native build of Qt 5.5 on the Raspberry, and I can qmake / make my programs. Now I have an issue : I can't seem to get it to run on the 2.8" TFT Monitor. It always launches on the HDMI monitor in full screen and I can't close it. I don't explicitly use OpenGL in my app. I use a Canvas but I set `renderTarget:Canvas.Image` .
My `main.cpp` is the one provided in the examples.
Any thoughts on how to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

QT redirect by default to DISPLAY:=0 (hdmi) You must change this by add a parameter to your executable program (-display)

more info here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-running.html